# How do I update iTunes Match info on my iOS 7 device?

Tags: itunes, ios, itunes-match

I have an iPhone running iOS 7.0.4. I use iTunes Match. I recently updated a bunch of meta data in iTunes on my PC. These updates have been pushed to iCloud and thence to iTunes on my other PCs. However, the iOS devices still have the old meta data after a couple of days.

I've tried killing the music app and rebooting the phone, to no avail. I'm looking for a little reload button (like at the top of the contacts list when contacts are synced with Google), but I'm not finding anything.

I haven't yet tried disabling iTunes Match and reenabling it. I fear that I will lose my downloaded songs, and that I'll have to rethink which ones to download and which not to.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off iTunes Match on my phone. All the Match songs that were downloaded were still available (cool!) and the non-downloaded ones were no longer listed. I then killed the Music app and rebooted the phone. Same thing. I then turned iTunes Match back on. It re downloaded all the metadata, but reattached to all my downloaded songs. It didn't need to re download them.
Pretty awesome.